# Find the order of an element of finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $g,h\in G-\{1\}$ such that $g^{-1}hg=h^2$.

In addition $o(g)=5$ and $o(h)$ is an odd integer. Find $o(h)$.

I know from a previous exercise that if there exists a natural number $i$ such that $g^{-1}hg=h^i$ then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $g^{-n}hg^n=h^{i^n}$.

I thought I could use this fact somehow, but so far no luck.

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try finishing off this line of argument...
$$
\begin{align}
h &= ehe \\&= g^{-5}hg^5 \\&= g^{-4} (g^{-1}h g) g^4 \\&= g^{-4}h^2 g^4 
\\&=g^{-3}(g^{-1}h^2g)g^3 \\&=g^{-3}h^4g^3 \\&= \dots \\&=h^?
\end{align}
$$
so $h^{?-1}=e$

Comment: This is not correct. You are suggesting a pattern that does not continue. $g^{-2} (g^{-1} h^4 g) g^{-2}$ we can group the $g^{-1}h^4g^{1}$ as $(g^{-1}hg^{1})^4 =  (h^2)^4 = h^8$. The term in the middle doubles with each step, it does not increase by $2$ every step.

Answer (score 5):

Square both sides
$$
g^{-1}h^2 g = h^4
$$
Now replace $h^2$
$$
g^{-1}(g^{-1} h g) g  = g^{-2} h g^2 = h^4
$$
Again square and expand
$$
g^{-3}hg^3 = g^{-2}h^2g^2 = h^8.
$$
By repeating this process we find
$$
g^{-k} h g^k = h^{2^k}
$$
for $k>0$
so in particular
$$
h = g^{-5}hg^5 = h^{32}.
$$
Hence $h^{31} = 1$. Thus $O(h)$ divides $31$. But $31$ is prime, so $O(h) = 1$ or $O(h) = 31$. Since we assumed $h \neq 1$, we find $O(h) = 31$.

Note here that the given information $O(h)$ is an odd integer was an unnecessary assumption. We could immediately see this by noting that the order of $h$ and any conjugate, e.g. $g^{-1}h g = h^2$, are the same. Thus $h,h^2$ have the same order, so $2$ is not a divisor of $O(h)$.

Answer (score 2):

$h=g^{-5}hg^5=g^{-4}h^2g=g^{-3}h^4g^3=g^{-2}h^8g^2=g^{-1}h^{16}g=g^{32}$.

So $g^{31}=e$. Since $31$ is prime the order is $31$.

---

I used $g^{-1}h^n g=(g^{-1}h g)^n$ which is straightforward, it is proven when we prove conjugate of product is product of conjugates, which is prove when we show conjugating by an element is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

By squaring both sides, you get $g^{-1}h^2 g = h^4$. This in turn means $g^{-2}hg^{2} = h^4$, by substituting for $h^2$ on the left hand side. You can keep doing this, until eventually you get $g^{-5}hg^5 = h^{32}$. Then $h = h^{32}$. So the order of $h$ (unless I've made some mistake) is either $1$ or $31$, since $31$ is prime. And since $1$ is ruled out as pointed out in a comment, that leaves just $31$ as the possible answer.

Comment: We know $o(h) \neq 1$ because of the hypothesis.

Comment: @Nitin Sorry I missed that. I updated the answer.